# Ajax jquery .load() error 404

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 $("#options li").click(function(){
  $("#mcont").load("ah.html",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
    if(statusTxt=="success")
      alert("External content loaded successfully!");
    if(statusTxt=="error")
      alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
 });
```

I'm new to ajax and I tried this jquery call but it gives me error 404.
ah.html is in the same directory with my page.

Comment: Can you add this line to your load code: `console.log(statusTxt);`

Comment: Check your webserver's logs (or your browser's Network panel) to see which path has been actually queried.

Comment: what does `ah.html` look like? and is it definitely `ah.html` and not `ah.htm`?

Comment: did you define a  Document type in html?

Comment: uhh, I managed to reproduce the problem and it only happens in google chrome. I viewed the sources and I cannot see my newly created folders and files. It works in firefox.